Fundamental group of degree 4 del Pezzo surface minus 16 (-1)-curves [Reference request]
Let $S$ be a degree $4$ del Pezzo surface (over $\mathbb{C}$).
That is, $5$ points blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$, or $4$ points blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. 
The classical fact is that $S$ has $16$ $(-1)$-curves.
My question is
What is the fundamental group of $S$ minus all $16$ $(-1)$-curves?
I appreciate any advice, answers, or references.
